# $.getJson fails when the result is a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a REST service for a Fizz Buzz game, it's working just fine and it's deployed to heroku (https://mighty-oasis-86817.herokuapp.com/play?inputText=3  just change the inputText parameter if necessary). And I'm trying to use it on a page and it's not working when the result is a text. 
It works just fine when the parameter is a single number and the result can be parsed into a number. But apparently when the result is not a number the parse fails(ex: 1 2 3 returns 1, 2, Fizz).
Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('https://mighty-oasis-86817.herokuapp.com/play?inputText=' + $('#inputText').val())
    .done( function (data) {
        alert(data);
    })
    .fail( function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

My object in the fail function considering the params were '1 2':

```
abort:ƒ (e)
always:ƒ ()
...
readyState: 4
responseText:"1, 2"
setRequestHeader:ƒ (e,t)
state:ƒ ()
status:200
statusCode:ƒ (e)
statusText:"parsererror"
...
```

Response log from one of the test cases:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
        Status = 200
 Error message = null
       Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json; charset=UTF-8], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], Content-Length=[18]}
  Content type = application/json; charset=UTF-8
          Body = 1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 98
 Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
       Cookies = []
```

Edit: Here is the object I'm returning in the java service.

```
ResponseEntity response = ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(sj.toString());
```

sj is a StringJoiner object.

Comment: It looks like your body isn't formatting as json, but as a CSV

Comment: If you're not retrieving json data, don't use getJSON()...

Comment: Thanks, simply changing from $.getJson to $.ajax and using dataType: "text" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
       $('#result').append(response);                        
    },
    error: function(response) {
       $('#result').append(response.responseText);
    }
});
```